# Why is the assembly instruction is wrong?

Tags: assembly

the assmbly instruction us :

movb $0xff, (%bl)

my question:

the assembly instruction is wrong, the answer said that %bl can not be address register. i can't understood this answer. please help me.(this is 32bits computer, AT&A assembly language)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is 32-bit mode assembly, an address can **only** be found in a 32-bit register. The construct `( )` uses the register (or expression) inside as an address, and `%bl` is an 8-bit register, so the instruction is incoherent. I don't think it can even be encoded.

Comment: I would also add that not all 32-bit registers can be used for addressing.

Comment: yeah, thanks your answer, i have understood this question, thanks

Comment: @icepack I don't mind adding a paragraph, but what 32-bit registers are you thinking about specifically that might be confused with the 32-bit registers that can be used for addressing?

Comment: Sorry, I got stuck in the 16-bit, where only `bx`, `dx`, `si` & `di` could be used for addressing. This limitation isn't present in 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

For x86 CPU all 8 bit register and the 16 bit register ax, cx and also dx can not be used as an address register within brackets[], but bx, si, di (with default segment DS) and bp and sp (with default segment SS) and for 80386+ all 32 bit register.